# Browsing gataGridView using entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm trying to learn Entity Framework using Windows Forms. My challenge is to find a method which displays only those rows that contains a text from searchTetbox, but I can find it nowhere.
The one thing I made so far is a code below (but I guess it's not EF at all...):

```
DataTable dataTable = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);

dataView.RowFilter = string.Format(comboBox1.Text.ToString() + " LIKE '{0}'", txtboxFind.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataView;
```

This code go throug debugging with no error, but every time text is searched - shows 0 rows as result. I guess that's because the dgv.DataSource = bindingSource and it cannot convert bindingsource to DataTable.

Any ideas how to fix this?
If it would be a part of EF, not a LINQ or else, it would be pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - your code is dealing with data tables, and this is not EF. If using EF, a very simple code snippet for filtering collection by a search string, would look similar to this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = yourListOfPocos.Where(a => a.Name == searchString).ToList();
```

But there are plenty of articles on this subject, just try with Google.

Comment: Works fine, I would give you +1 if I could (too low reputation ):

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string Query = String.Format(@"({1} like '%{0}%' or {2} like '%{0}%')", txtBoxFind.Text.trim(),"ColumnName1","ColumnName2");
(dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(Query);
```